Include conditional statement in a Sphinx template
I was wondering how can I include a conditional statement inside a sphinx template?
For now, I'm using sphinx.ext.autosummary to generate my API reference. I have the file _templates/autosummary/function.rst which is my template for every function I want to include in the documentation. Here is the content of the function.rst file:
{{ fullname | underline}}

.. currentmodule:: {{ module }}

.. autofunction:: {{ objname }}

.. plot:: code/reference/{{ objname }}.py

So it tries to fetch a python file using the sphinx extension matplotlib.sphinxext.plot_directive to display a plot for every function.
As the Python library describes by the doc uses geographic objects, it is important to have a representation of the output of a function. But sometimes, a function does not do anything geographically visible, so it makes no sense to include a plot.
Can I use a conditional statement so if the python file doesn't exist, sphinx doesn't throw an error?
